# PostSharp and StructureMap

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, structuremap, postsharp

So I was reading [this](http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/Day-7-Interception-Aspects-e28093-Part-1) fun article from Dustin Davis and decided to try it on my own with PostSharp 2.1.7.30 and StructureMap 2.6.4.1.

```
using System;
using PostSharp.Aspects;

namespace StructureMap
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => { 
                x.For(typeof (IDbFind)).Use(typeof (DbFind)); });
            var w = new Worker();
            var f = w.Finder;
        }
    }

    internal class Worker
    {
        [IoCResolution] private IDbFind finder;
        public IDbFind Finder
        {
            get { return finder; }
        }
    }

    internal class DbFind : IDbFind
    {
    }

    internal interface IDbFind
    {
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class IoCResolution : LocationInterceptionAspect
    {
        public override void OnGetValue(LocationInterceptionArgs args)
        {
            args.ProceedGetValue();
            if (args.Value == null)
            {
                object obj = ObjectFactory.GetInstance(
                    args.Location.PropertyInfo.PropertyType);
                args.Value = obj;
                args.ProceedSetValue();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately during execution I get this error:

```
{"The type initializer for '<>z__Aspects' threw an exception."}
```

With an Inner Exception of:

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'StructureMap, Version=1.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The 
located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"StructureMap, Version=1.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"}
```

FusionLog:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = StructureMap, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
(Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Scratch/StructureMap/StructureMap/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : PostSharp, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b13fd38b8f9c99d7.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Scratch\StructureMap\StructureMap\bin\Debug\StructureMap.vshost.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Scratch/StructureMap/StructureMap/bin/Debug/StructureMap.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: PUBLIC KEY TOKEN
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

**UPDATE 5 minutes later:**
I'm an idiot ... This will teach me not to call my namespace the same as a 3rd party DLL. After changing namespace to StructureMapPlay, it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the namespace to StructureMapPlay, in code and project properties.